# how to dispose current page when using Navigator.pop in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am using `Navigator.pop(context);` to exit current page, but I want to dispose current page after pop(because current page has some gif animation and may cause other problem, it will rendering in backend will make the GPU busy all the time, and make the device heat quickly), what should I do to make it work like this? I am tried to

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "..");
```

but I do not know how to specify the second paramter becuase it has many entry with current page, I have to specify the relative path.By the way, I am using [flutter html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) to load the gif animation, the animation did not control by myself but the flutter html component. This is part of the code:

```
if (item.content != "")
              Html(
                  data: item.content,
                  style: {
                    "body": Style(
                      fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                    ),
                  },
                  customImageRenders: defaultImageRenders,
                  onLinkTap: (String? url, RenderContext context, Map<String, String> attributes, dom.Element? element) {
                    CommonUtils.launchUrl(url);
                  }),
```

Comment: Why don't you dispose the animation controller when leaving the page?

Comment: Thank you, I would foun the flutter html to find if it give the gif animation controller api. @Akif

Comment: I think to solve the problem , I should dispose the page which popup.